# Errors with running slack bolt (Python) locally

Tags: python, web-applications, slack, slack-api

I'm deploying this code https://github.com/misscoded/webinar-bolt-python-nov-2020 on my PC, but I am getting the error as shown below. I tried to remove the App initialization but still got the same error.

The code:

```
app = App(
  signing_secret=os.environ.get('SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET'),
  token=os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"),
)
```

The error:

```
line 10, in <module>
    app = App(
  File "C:\Users\Ruba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\slack_bolt\app\app.py", line 208, in __init__
    self._init_middleware_list()
  File "C:\Users\Ruba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\slack_bolt\app\app.py", line 232, in _init_middleware_list
    raise BoltError(error_token_required())
slack_bolt.error.BoltError: Either an env variable `SLACK_BOT_TOKEN` or `token` argument in the constructor is required.
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Windows, check your environment variables (Control Panel -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables) and ensure the system is picking them up. From the error message, it looks like it's not reading them, but I may be wrong.

Also, familiarize yourself with Slack's [Bolt Framework](https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python). It has something called [Socket Mode](https://slack.dev/bolt-python/concepts#socket-mode) which makes local development so much easier and quicker.

Comment: No problem! If this answered your question, kindly mark it as answered so it can help others also. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After you update your tokens within your app, make sure to also update the tokens in your .env file and your .bash_profile as well on your local environment.